# Unknown server tag 'webopt:BundleReference'

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a web form in ASP.Net 4.5 using Visual Studio 2012 for Web Express. It is hosted on somee.com. When the page loads I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service        this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'webopt:BundleReference'.

Source Error: 


Line 9: <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
Line 10: </asp:PlaceHolder> 
Line 11: <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" /> 
Line 12: <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
Line 13: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

Source File: /Site.Master Line: 11 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET  Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Comment: Downloading the `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms` package from NuGet fixed the issue for me: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms/

Comment: Even if installed can still get this error if the package needs updating, easy from the console installed tab search on webforms, worth checking.

Answer (score 10):

It's simpler than that actually.
Simply run this on Nuget: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to ensure that you have a reference to the specific assembly that is related to your "webopt" files. Typically, you can do this by including it within the  section of your web.config file :

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="webopt" assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms"  />
    </controls>
</pages>
```

Comment: I found the problem. I published a debug version to the website. Published a release version and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Bundling and minification can be turned on simply by setting the debug attribute to `false` in `web.config`.

Comment: You should add some explanation of how and why this will help.

Comment: This removed the warning message for me.  Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--You can set debug attribute to ="false"-->
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms"       namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
  </controls>
 </pages>
 </system.web>
```

---

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/19/building-a-basic-web-forms-application-using-visual-studio-2013.aspx

---

please read : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prashant_upadhyay/archive/2011/07/15/pros-and-cons-of-using-debug-true-in-asp-net-applications-in-production-environment.aspx?Redirected=true

---

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Web.config and check 'Build Action' property. If it is set to 'None' you will see 'Unknown server tag 'webopt:bundlereference' error. Change it to 'Content' and everything will be OK.