# Unknown server tag 'webopt:bundlereference' error while publishing Web Forms application using VS2013

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013, publish

While publishing the web forms application using VS2013 I am getting 2 errors repeated several times. These are:

1. /Site.Master(14,0):Error ASPPARSE: Unknown server tag `'webopt:bundlereference'`.
2. /Site.Master(20,0): Error ASPPARSE: Unknown server tag `'ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager'`.

I have tried the following taking a cue from [Unknown server tag 'webopt:BundleReference'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130988/unknown-server-tag-weboptbundlereference)

1. Publish in Release version instead of Debug
2. `debug=false` in web.config
3. Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms` is already in the solution
4. web.config reference for the two assemblies is already there in the `<control>` section.

Nothing seems to be working. **The solutions runs fine from within VS2013.**

Any help please!

Comment: **WORKAOUND - ** Use @Register directive on every page where you use AjaxControlToolkit control. The code Builds and Runs in development environment WITHOUT this when ACT is referenced in Web.Config file but Publish Fails!